# html to remove border from inner table

Tags: html, css, width, border

i would like to remove the border from the sides and the bottom of my inner table and stretch it so that it becomes as long as the outer table. I have tried using border-right: none; in my css for bottom, right, and left but the border on those sides of the inner table always stay no matter how wide I make the inner table to meet the outer table. What html/css can I use to hide the border of my inner table but keep the border around the tds?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your code.

Comment: You should post your code here.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure of what you want to achieve, but this could be helping:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

To ensure there is no extra space between outer and inner borders of the table.

Afterwards, it may just be a matter of enabling or disabling the borders, the way you where saying, both on < td>s' and < table>s'.